# images missing after grunt build with videojs

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I've got an angular app I created with yeoman's angular generator. I added the videojs player, listed it in the bower.json file. All is good in dev, but when I do a build, the videojs images are missing. Anyone know how to track this down or what to do?

thanks!
iain

Comment: Check the Network tab of dev tools in your browser for 404's, then compare the differences in what you see in folders for dev vs dist. You may end up having to hardcode in some of the files outside of the portion of your code that is dynamically generated by Grunt. Can't speak specifically to videojs, but I've seen this happen before with other packages such as fontawesome.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you the hacky way I did this was creating a "font" folder with the videojs fonts in my app/styles folder and then adding that path to my copy directive in bower.json. There is probably a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same problem. The least hacky way I could come up with was referencing the bower-installed library in copy.dist.files in Gruntfile.js.

```
{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'bower_components/video.js/dist/video-js',
  dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles',
  src: ['font/*']
}
```